# Handle exception in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to handle an exception in Visual Studio Community 2019, note that I am not sure if I have an error with my settings or it is because of my code.

The exception that I am trying to handle is out_of_range. In order to do it I put it within a try block and catch, but I am unable to handle.
When the program runs it prompts a window : Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression vector subscript out of range

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
int main() {


    try {
        cout << "throwing exception: \n";
        throw 1;
    }
    catch (int i) {
        cout << "exception happended!\n";
    }
    cout << "out of exception\n";
    vector<int> v;
    try {
        cout << "throwing exception2: \n";
        v[2];
    }
    catch (out_of_range e) {
        cout << "Exception out of range\n";
        cout << e.what();
    }
    catch (exception& d) {
        cout << "General Exception\n";
        cout << d.what();
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "special excpetinon\n";
    }
    cout << "Exception handled!";
}
```

The first exception I am able to handle and the programs continues whereas in the second one the program is stopped and its showing the window Error.

I run the program in debug mode, with the default settings:

[image: VS Exception Settings]

I would like to handle the second exception the same way as the first one.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the vector's [] throws an exception?

Comment: wow thx, so fast. I thought you could handle it in a similar way of java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Thank you!

Comment: In the Debug build, the iterator debugging feature is enabled by default.  Controlled by the [`_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/has-iterator-debugging?view=vs-2019) macro.  Very helpful to catch programming mistakes, turning it off is not a great idea.  If you want to test your exception handling code then just press F5 to continue running the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debug Assertion Failed! Expression vector subscript out of range

isn't an exception. That's the debugger telling you your program went out of bounds and stopped you so you could inspect the program and learn how it happened in order to prevent the program going out of bounds. You can't catch this. You need to fix the bug that allowed the program to access invalid memory.

C++ has a policy of not making a program pay for anything that isn't explicitly asked for. In this case, the checking necessary to allow a catch-able exception to be thrown slows down the program, so the [`[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) operator doesn't perform any checks<sup>1</sup>. You get a faster program, but you-the-programmer have to promise that the program will never go out of bounds.

The [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) method does check and will throw an exception, but by using `at` you've opted-in for a slightly slower program.

<sup>1</sup>Doesn't *require* any checks is a better way to word this. In this case the `vector` implementation in the debug version of the MicroSoft  standard library implementation *does* check by default and the "Debug Assertion Failed!" message is the direct result. Debug  builds are optimized to make debugging easier and tend to be slow. This checking doesn't happen in the release library because the release builds are optimized for performance.